# Как сделать чтобы на GitHub Pages открывался index.html находящийся в подпапке?

Tags: github

Создал сайт на GitHub Pages, залит туда свой проект и он не работал, потому что у меня все html файлы и стили лежать в папке assets. Переместил их в корень и все работает как надо. Но это неудобно, так как у меня там и папка node_modules и много конфиг файлов.
 Можно ли что-то сделать, чтобы переходя по адресу yourName.github.io открывался индекс файл расположенный не в корне а в папке? Имя папки совершенно без разницы какое. Погуглил но что-то не смог разобраться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще говоря, есть три способа организовать GitHub Pages:

- Положить все страницы напрямую в ветку с названием `master`. Подходит, если в репозитории кроме сайта ничего нет (видимо, не ваш случай).
- Положить все страницы в ветку `gh-pages`. Она не обязательно должна иметь предка в мастере.
- Положить все страницы в папку `/docs` в корне репозитория в ветке `master`.

Я в основном видел, что всё, относящееся к GitHub Pages, кладут в ветку `gh-pages`. Мне кажется, это самый популярный способ.

[По материалам руководства «Configuring a publishing source for GitHub Pages».](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

---

Создать ветку для GitHub Pages можно, например, таким образом:

```bash
git checkout --orphan gh-pages
git reset !(assets)
git mv assets/* .
git commit
```